# Get all Mint Wallets from a Creator Address

Tags: web3.js, nft, nfts, solana-cli, mint

Can anyone help me with a snippet that delivers all wallets that actually minted (not holding) from a certain creator id?

There's a Transfer Type "Mint" that I can see on Solscan but I'm really struggling to get it all together

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the `Candy Machine` address, and process all the `transactions` and filter out the `mint` events and who received them.

Comment: Can you guide me with a little code there to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to create the mint list for the collection, and there are various tools available, such as Famous Fox Snapshot (https://famousfoxes.com/snapshot), that can assist with this task. Once you've compiled the list of tokens within the collection, you can directly query the RPC to identify the largest accounts (https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettokenlargestaccounts). Given that it's an NFT collection, only one account is expected to have a positive balance. You can repeat this process for each token on the mint list.